# How to solve the equation for general k?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Assume $k>0$ is a parameter, and the function $f(x)$ is given by
$$f(x)=e^{kx}-ke^{-x}-k+1.$$ 
How can I calculate the $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$?

First of all, I let $y=e^{x}$, then the equation becomes $f(y)=y^k-ky^{-1}-k+1$. It is worthing noting that when $y\rightarrow 0$, $f(y) \rightarrow -\infty$. When $y\rightarrow +\infty$, $f(y) \rightarrow +\infty$. Thus, there exists at least one $y_0$ such that $f(y_0)=0$. However, I do not konw how to find the closed-form of the solution.

Comment: There is no closed form, though you can attempt to write the root using things such as Lagrange inversion theorrm.

Comment: Nice exercise for numerical methods.

Comment: If this problem is important, I guess that a pretty good *estimate* could be generated. Is it worth I spend time on that issue ?

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer.*

As said in comments, there is no hope for a closed form and numerical methods should be used. More than likely, Newton method would be the simplest; however, as usual, the problem is the initial guess $x_0$.

Considering the case where $k >1$ for which the solution is $>0$, I tried to generate some estimate building the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant of the original function. This gives (this is just an example for $n=5$)
$$x_0=\frac{12 (k-1) \left(k^8+16 k^7+41 k^6+36 k^5+52 k^4+36 k^3+41 k^2+16
   k+1\right)}{(k+1)^2 \left(2 k^8+60 k^7+157 k^6+282 k^4+157 k^2+60 k+2\right)}$$

Trying for a few integer values of $k$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimation} & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 0.419652 &  0.419618 \\
 3 & 0.454355 &  0.454092 \\
 4 & 0.431354 &  0.430701 \\
 5 & 0.400189 &  0.399069 \\
 6 & 0.370539 &  0.368937 \\
 7 & 0.344242 &  0.342186 \\
 8 & 0.321299 &  0.318836 \\
 9 & 0.301296 &  0.298480 \\
 10 & 0.283772 &  0.280656 \\
 20 & 0.182806 &  0.178793 \\
 30 & 0.137075 &  0.133726 \\
 40 & 0.110350 &  0.107907 \\
 50 & 0.092613 &  0.091004\\
 60 & 0.079908 &  0.079001 \\
 70 & 0.070327 &  0.069998 \\
 80 & 0.062830 &  0.062972 \\
 90 & 0.056796 &  0.057322 \\
 100 & 0.051831 &  0.052672 \\
 200 & 0.027734 &  0.029871 \\
 300 & 0.018954 &  0.021282 \\
 400 & 0.014400 &  0.016688 \\
 500 & 0.011612 &  0.013800 \\
 600 & 0.009728 &  0.011806 \\
 700 & 0.008371 &  0.010341 \\
 800 & 0.007345 &  0.009216 \\
 900  & 0.006544 & 0.008323 \\
 1000 & 0.005901 & 0.007600
\end{array}
\right)$$
For sure, when $k$ is large, the estimate is poorer and poorer. Let us try for $k=1234.56789$. Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.00479442 \\
 1 & 0.00933283 \\
 2 & 0.00854256 \\
 3 & 0.00778491 \\
 4 & 0.00710836 \\
 5 & 0.00660608 \\
 6 & 0.00636824 \\
 7 & 0.00632569 \\
 8 & 0.00632453
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

What could be interesting is that we can solve the equation for $k$. It is
$$k=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}-\frac{W\left(-\frac{ x}{e^x+1}t\right)}{x}\qquad \text{with}\qquad t=e^{\frac{e^x x}{e^x+1}+x}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. The solution is real as long as $x < 0.455$ and it is valid for any $k$.

So, $x$ is "just" the inverse function of the monster.